# write java interface

Tags: java, automated-tests

as I declare a table of strings in all java testss and functions , is it possible de declare it once in an interface and to call it anywhere ?

```
public interface string {

 string[] mytab = new string[2]; 


}

in the java class : 
public class Test { }
```

How can I call the inetrface to say :

```
if (mytab[1].equals("toto")){}
```

Comment: Clarify your question. I think you are looking for a Utility class with a list of static variables.

Comment: @Bozho: it seems that comments like yours are most popular to his posts. +1 nevertheless.

Comment: teja ,I do not think that these kind of answers help people to progress !

Comment: Peter ,
if I ask questions it is because I do not know how to do it , but if before giving any answer we said : clarify your questions,you need to accept answers whatever answers is clarify your question =>no I'm not satisfaied we should wait my clarification before saying this bellow someone gave an answer which is clear to me !

Comment: And the comment `ok thelost , thanks` sounds like you are actually satisfied with an answer - so if it solved your problem, accept it. Otherwise, provide information why it does not solve your problem.

Comment: I haven't ask this question before...
the other questions I reask them because no one give me answers
when I say , ok thanks it mean that it is ok for me it solves my problem!

Comment: ??? how do I accept it ??? i said ok thanks that means it solvs my problem!!

Comment: I am upvoting this because I think "-3" essentially means bullying to me. If someone thinks a question is not clear enough a "-1" or "-2" should be enough. -3 means we have about 20 experts (who know how SO works) bullying someone who is new to things :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are asking about. This should work for you.

```
public interface MyInterface {

    static final String myString = "abc";

}


public class Test {

static void test() {
        if (MyInterface.myString.equals("abc")) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can define static objects in an interface.